# PHP returning non-parsed HTML characters in string

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I'm at a loss of what I'm doing wrong here, but I need to return an array of strings separated by line breaks, and when I return the imploded string it's actually including the HTML tags as text, non-parsed.

Here's my code:

```
if (!empty($college)){
$return[] = $college;
}
if (!empty($precollege)){
$return[] = $precollege;
}
if (!empty($evening_division)) {
$return[] = $evening_division;
}
if (!empty($music_advancement_program)) {
$return[] = $music_advancement_program;
}
$test = implode("<br/>",$return);

return $test;
```

However, the function is returning strings with the HTML characters typed out as tags "< br />", not as actual line breaks. I need to return the string to the template to render the data, so the string needs to be formatted with the proper line breaks. I've also tried \n as well to no avail. This is from a preprocess function that's creating variables that are accessible in a Drupal 8 twig file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the complete code,

According to: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-best-practices-preprocess-functions-and-templates

You should do it as follows:

```
function your_function(&$variables) {
    if (!empty($college)){
        $return[] = $college;
    }
    if (!empty($precollege)){
        $return[] = $precollege;
    }
    if (!empty($evening_division)) {
        $return[] = $evening_division;
    }
    if (!empty($music_advancement_program)) {
        $return[] = $music_advancement_program;
    }

    $variables['test'] = t(implode("<br/>", $return));
}
```

Then in your template, access like:

```
<div>{{ test }}</div>
```